# A better way to compare Strings which could be null

Tags: java, string

I was just wondering if there is a better way to do this. i feel it might be inefficient. Problem is for DB reasons i need to compare strings which can sometimes be null or not.

```
public static boolean compareStrings(String str1, String str2){

    if(str1 == null && str2 == null) return true;

    if(str1 != null && str2 != null){
        if(str1.equals(str2))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: migrate to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/...?

Comment: so sorry thanks will do so in future

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The usual idiom is this:

```
return (str1 == null ? str2 == null : str1.equals(str2));
```

Comment: I would like to just add that I was doing this for android and TextUtils.equals(a, b); does exactly this

Answer (score 34):

You say that these are potentially coming from a database. At that point, any inefficiencies around a few nullity tests are entirely insignificant compared with the cost of database queries, to be honest. I would focus on the readability.

To that end, I would start using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) and its [`Objects`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html) class:

```
boolean equal = Objects.equal(a, b);
```

I would expect that to be implemented as per Taymon's code, basically - but it's nice to have it in *one* place.

**EDIT:** For Java 7+ you don't need Guava. You can just use `java.util.Objects.equals(a, b)`.

Comment: As far as "readability" ... that really makes me think of `object.ReferenceEquals`, which isn't a good thing :(

Comment: @pst: It should make you think of the static `object.Equals` method, which is the equivalent already built-into .NET.

Comment: For anyone coming across this more recently, the same thing is now in Java 7: [Objects.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 4):

If you are open to using apache Commons StringUtils then they have equals which compares two strings null-safe

Answer (score 1):

This code would only be inefficient if it causes a bottleneck during a normal execution of your program.  The only way to know if this is the case is to run your program through a profiler.  Until you do that and see for a fact that this function causes performance problems, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: It might be a bit picky for me to worry about this especially without profiling. I usually dont use profilers unless I come across memory leaks. I was more or less wondering if there was a better implementation than developing a static method of my own. Thank you