# String comparisions in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A better way to compare Strings which could be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336856/a-better-way-to-compare-strings-which-could-be-null)

I have an if condition which looks like this :

```
if( !str1.equals(str2) )
{
    ---
    ---
    ---
}
```

where str1 and str2 are two string objects.

There are chances that str1 might be null , so is the below code equivalent to the above, along with handling the null check?

```
if( !(str1==null ? str2==null : str1.equals(str2)) )
{
    ---
    ---
    ---
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how you imagine the null check being handled in the bit of code that is just in your head.

Comment: If `str1` is `null` then if you will do `str1.equals();` you will get `NullPointerException`.
For more detail check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601978/how-to-check-if-my-string-is-equal-to-null

Comment: Your condition looks fine. You could rewrite it as `if( str1==null ? str2!=null : !str1.equals(str2) )` which might be easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that will lead to the same result.

To be a bit more specific:

1. If `str1` *isn't* null, it's *exactly* the same, since it just passes through the ternary check to the same expression as before
2. If `str1` *is* null, it then becomes a check to see if `str2` is *also* null.

And since you have the whole ternary expression wrapped up with the `!` out front, that behaves the same as before.

If you wanted to be a *bit* more clear, you could make `str2==null` into an actual comparison between `str1` and `str2`: `str1==str2`. Since one of the values is already `null`, it doesn't matter that it's a referential check instead of a proper string equality check, and ends up being a bit more clear in the code (to me, anyways)

As others have mentioned, however, the Apache Commons library already includes this null-safe equality capability, but it does require a rather substantial library inclusion. On the other hand, many feel that the Apache Commons functionality should be effectively considered a part of Java itself, so you can decide for yourself if you want the extra dependency.

Lastly, the functionality isn't *technically* equivalent, since the default `.equals()` method will throw a `NullPointerException`, while your equality check code *won't*. If that is the behavior you were looking for (which I assume it is), then you're fine, but it is something to be aware of.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want two nulls to be equal, sure.  Depending on your method, NullPointerException may be the correct response.  You can save yourself a lot of typing by getting to know

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
```

`!StringUtils.equals(str1, str2);` handles the nulls for you in the same way.

Comment: Apache string utils can be a huge help to any project, why reinvent the wheel!

Comment: +1 for suggesting apache commons StringUtils before I got there. StringUtils is very useful for exactly this kind of thing, comparisons that handle nulls correctly.

Comment: It can also introduce a large dependency when a very small amount of code would suffice...

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Java 7:

```
java.util.Objects.equals(str1, str2);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct, if you consider `null`s equal, and allow `str2` to be `null`. But it would be better for you not to beleive anybody, but write a test for all possible cases.

Answer (score 1):

Using the ternary operator is a really silly way of doing that check, and it makes your could frustrating to read. Just use an AND.

```
if(str1 != null && !str1.equals(str2))
{
    ---
    ---
    ---
}
```

You don't need to import a whole new library to do a null check.

Comment: +1 amen for the sanity of a simple solution instead of using a library...

Comment: This doesn't check to see if `str2` is equal (ie. null == null) to `str1`. Instead, this code says that if `str1 == null`, then it _can't_ be equal to `str2`. This answer also doesn't answer the question of if the two options are equal.

Comment: @cdeszaq The OP wants to go into the if statement if str1 and str2 _are not equal_. That is what his very first if statement does. All this code does is ensures that str1 is also _not_ null. You will notice if you re-read the post, that the OP isn't concerned with str2 being null.

Comment: With the code you provided, if `str2 == null` and `str1 == null`, you would not enter the block, even though `str2 == str1`. So, your code fails the test where both inputs are null, since your code does not consider them equal, even though they are.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen The OP wants to check if `str1` and `str2` are not equal. They only mention `str1` because if `str1` is `null`, `str1.equals(str2)` will cause an NPE. They clearly *are* concerned about `str2`, as seen in the second piece of code in the question. Your answer fails when both are `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code will enter the `if` block only if the strings are unequal (either only one of them is null or both of them are not null and different).

Another way to do it is

```
if( (str1 == null && str2 != null) || !str1.equals(str2) ){
    // Only executes when strings are unequal
}
```

It's a matter of taste, some people are allergic to ternary operators. (I like them).