# Compare two objects in Java with possible null values

Tags: java

I want to compare two strings for equality when either or both can be `null`.

So, I can't simply call `.equals()` as it can contain `null` values.

The code I have tried so far :

```
boolean compare(String str1, String str2) {
  return ((str1 == str2) || (str1 != null && str1.equals(str2)));
}
```

What will be the best way to check for all possible values including `null` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A better way to compare Strings which could be null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336856/a-better-way-to-compare-strings-which-could-be-null)

Comment: Note that it is a bit confusing that you call the method `compare`, it has a different meaning for strings.  You should call it `equals`.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

This is what Java internal code uses (on other `compare` methods):

```
public static boolean compare(String str1, String str2) {
    return (str1 == null ? str2 == null : str1.equals(str2));
}
```

Comment: Why not just change the String types to Objects - making it more generic?  And then it is the same as what you will get if you move to Java 7.

Comment: Which java class contains method you provided?

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi This particular `compare` method is not in the Java JDK. If it was, I would suggest using that.

Comment: Hey! you shouldn't have a compare method returning true/false. Equals is not the same as compare. Compare should be useful for sorting. You should return `<0`, `==0` or `>0` to indicate which one is lower/grater than the other

Comment: i suggest using `Objects.equals(Object, Object)` as Mark Rotteveel has pointed out in his answer (please upvote it)

Comment: @LonelyNeuron That only applies to Java 7+.

Comment: This is the *clearest* implementation, but the answer added to the question checks reference equality first, so is *faster* (if many strings are interned), even though it has worst-case three comparisons. I choose clarity!

Comment: @hyperpallium the first thing, `String.equals` does internally, is a reference comparison, like `if(this == other) return true;`. Since `String` is `final`, even the simplest JVMs will be capable of inlining that code, not to speak of modern common implementations. So if the strings are identical (equal and interned), the early reference comparison doesn’t gain much and in all other cases, it doesn’t help at all, except for the scenario where both are `null`, perhaps.

Answer (score 505):

Since Java 7 you can use the static method [`java.util.Objects.equals(Object, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to perform equals checks on two objects without caring about them being `null`.

If both objects are `null` it will return `true`, if one is `null` and another isn't it will return `false`. Otherwise it will return the result of calling [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) on the first object with the second as argument.

Comment: this approach defers the type check until the runtime of the program. two consequences: it will be slower at runtime and IDE won't let you know if you by accident try to compare different types.

Comment: @averasko When you use `Object.equals(Object)` there is no compile time type check. The `Objects.equals(Object, Object)` works very much the same as a  normal `equals`, and re inference/checks by IDE, those rules are heuristics that are also supported for `Objects.equals(Object, Object)` (eg IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 has the same check for both the normal equals and the one from Objects).

Comment: I like this approach. No need to include some ApacheCommons library for things these days.

Comment: @SimonBaars This isn't running a function on a null object, this is a static method that you pass two arguments, which can be null, or a reference to an object.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah, didn't read it too well. Thought you could just do object.equals(object) and the compiler fixed it into something that would prevent a NullPointerException.

Comment: imho this should be the accepted answer. I don't want to reinvent the wheel in every single application I write

Comment: pls include package: `java.util.Objects`

Comment: @hyperpallium I link to the Javadoc, and any decent IDE will automatically suggest the import for you, but I'll add it.

Comment: This is not helpful as it will always give false for 2 different objects having the exact same properties and values.

Comment: @saran3h That means that you haven't overridden `equals(Object)` in that class. See also [Why this two simple objects are not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658385/why-this-two-simple-objects-are-not-equal)

Answer (score 56):

For these cases it would be better to use [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [StringUtils#equals](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#equals(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), it already handles null strings. Code sample:

```
public boolean compare(String s1, String s2) {
    return StringUtils.equals(s1, s2);
}
```

If you dont want to add the library, just copy the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java#StringUtils.equals%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) of the `StringUtils#equals` method and apply it when you need it.

Comment: java.util.Objects is best since Java7, see other answer

Answer (score 29):

For those on android, who can't use API 19's Objects.equals(str1, str2), there is this:

```
android.text.TextUtils.equals(str1, str2);
```

It is null safe.  It rarely has to use the more expensive string.equals() method because identical strings on android almost always compare true with the "==" operand thanks to [Android's String Pooling](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html), and length checks are a fast way to filter out most mismatches.

Source Code:

```
/**
 * Returns true if a and b are equal, including if they are both null.
 * <p><i>Note: In platform versions 1.1 and earlier, this method only worked  well if
 * both the arguments were instances of String.</i></p>
 * @param a first CharSequence to check
 * @param b second CharSequence to check
 * @return true if a and b are equal
 */
public static boolean equals(CharSequence a, CharSequence b) {
    if (a == b) return true;
    int length;
    if (a != null && b != null && (length = a.length()) == b.length()) {
        if (a instanceof String && b instanceof String) {
            return a.equals(b);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i)) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Using **Java 8:**

```
private static Comparator<String> nullSafeStringComparator = Comparator
        .nullsFirst(String::compareToIgnoreCase); 

private static Comparator<Metadata> metadataComparator = Comparator
        .comparing(Metadata::getName, nullSafeStringComparator)
        .thenComparing(Metadata::getValue, nullSafeStringComparator);

public int compareTo(Metadata that) {
    return metadataComparator.compare(this, that);
}
```

Or you can use the method below using Java:

```java
public static boolean compare(String first, String second) {
    return(Objects.isNull(first) ? Objects.isNull(second) : 
       first.equals(second));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Since version 3.5 Apache Commons StringUtils has the following methods:

```
static int  compare(String str1, String str2)
static int  compare(String str1, String str2, boolean nullIsLess)
static int  compareIgnoreCase(String str1, String str2)
static int  compareIgnoreCase(String str1, String str2, boolean nullIsLess)
```

These provide null safe String comparison.

Answer (score 6):

Compare two string using equals(-,-) and equalsIgnoreCase(-,-) method of Apache Commons StringUtils class.

**StringUtils.equals(-, -)** :

```
StringUtils.equals(null, null)   = true
StringUtils.equals(null, "abc")  = false
StringUtils.equals("abc", null)  = false
StringUtils.equals("abc", "abc") = true
StringUtils.equals("abc", "ABC") = false
```

**StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(-, -)** :

```
StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(null, null)   = true
StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(null, "abc")  = false
StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("xyz", null)  = false
StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("xyz", "xyz") = true
StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("xyz", "XYZ") = true
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use  `java.util.Objects` as following.

```
public static boolean compare(String str1, String str2) {
    return Objects.equals(str1, str2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean compare(String str1, String str2) {
    if(str1==null || str2==null) {
        //return false; if you assume null not equal to null
        return str1==str2;
    }
    return str1.equals(str2);
}
```

is this what you desired?

Comment: This case returns `false` if both Strings are `null` which might not be the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean compare(String str1, String str2) {
    if (str1 == null || str2 == null)
        return str1 == str2;

    return str1.equals(str2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean compare(String str1, String str2) {
  return (str1==null || str2==null) ? str1 == str2 : str1.equals(str2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what does "best possible solution" mean?

If you mean most readable, then all the possible solutions are pretty much equivalent for an experienced Java programmer.  But IMO the most readable is this

```
 public boolean compareStringsOrNulls(String str1, String str2) {
     // Implement it how you like
 }
```

In other words, hide the implementation inside a simple method that (ideally) can be inlined.

(You could also "out-source" to a 3rd party utility library ... if you already use it in your codebase.)

---

If you mean most performant, then:

1. the most performant solution depends on the platform and the context,
2. one of the "context" issues is the relative (dynamic) frequency of occurrence of `null` arguments,
3. it *probably* doesn't matter which version is faster ... because the difference is probably too small to make a difference to the overall application performance, and
4. if it does matter, the only way to figure out which is fastest ON YOUR PLATFORM is to try both versions and measure the difference.