# java.lang.NullPointerException: 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```java
if (chat_message.getReceiver().equals("myid") 
    && chat_message.getSender().equals("userid") 
    || chat_message.getReceiver().equals("userid") 
    && chat_message.getSender().equals("myid")
)
```

I get this error?

I did everything right, firebase is also right.

When I enter the application, it closes immediately. Does anyone know the reason?

The error I got:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: One of chat_message.getReceiver() or .getSender() returns null.

Comment: You need to format your code and provide a bit more context precise answers.

Comment: Related: [Compare two objects in Java with possible null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271554/compare-two-objects-in-java-with-possible-null-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the IDs of sender/receiver are constant strings `"myid"/"userid"` it is better to use Joda (inverted) conditions to prevent NullPointerException:

```java
final String sender = chat_message.getSender();
final String receiver = chat_message.getReceiver();

if (("myid".equals(sender) && "userid".equals(receiver)) 
    || ("myid".equals(receiver) && "userid".equals(sender)) 
)
```